# Install newer unix sort command without root permission

Tags: rhel, software-installation, upgrade, non-root-user

The unix server I am using has an old version of sort installed (no -V option), would it be possible to install a newer version locally (I do not have root permissions)?  Where would I download it and how would I install it?  I would like this new version to be the default every time I connect to the server.

As a reference I am using the following version:

```
sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.25(1)-release

./unix_distro.sh 
Linux RedHat 5.5(Final 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 x86_64)

uname -a
Linux tin.broadinstitute.org 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Jul 1 19:04:48 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You can compile and install a newer version of coreutils in your home directory, but it will only be available to your user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you compile and install a newer version without root?  Yes.

Can you install it in place of the old one?  No.

It used to be fairly common for normal users to have `bin` directories in their home directories.  It's become less common now that everyone can have their own Linux/UNIX box on their desk.

When you used `configure` you could change the prefix so it installs in your home directory, and then change your `PATH` to include `~/bin` before the standard system stuff.

```
export PATH=~/bin:${PATH}
```

You have to add it to the front because otherwise the old version will run instead.

You could even open up permissions so others could change their `PATH` to include your stuff.  But they should really trust you before doing that.  Otherwise you could slip malicious programs in.

Comment: excellent answer, thanks a lot!  tryin it now...